# Ruby path management

Tags: ruby, relative-path

What is the best way to manage the require paths in a ruby program?

Let me give a basic example, consider a structure like:

```
\MyProgram

\MyProgram\src\myclass.rb

\MyProgram\test\mytest.rb
```

If in my test i use `require '../src/myclass'` then I can only call the test from `\MyProgram\test` folder, but I want to be able to call it from any path!

The solution I came up with is to define in all source files the following line:

`ROOT = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/.." unless defined?(ROOT)` and then always use `require "#{ROOT}/src/myclass"`

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 32):

As of Ruby 1.9 you can use [require_relative](http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html#M000039) to do this:

```
require_relative '../src/myclass'
```

If you need this for earlier versions you can get it from the extensions gem as per [this SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681031/beginner-to-ruby-require-relative-problem/2681062#2681062).

Answer (score 12):

Here is a slightly modified way to do it:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "..", "src"))
```

By prepending the path to your source to $LOAD_PATH (aka $:) you don't have to supply the root etc. explicitly when you require your code i.e.  `require 'myclass'`

Answer (score 9):

The same, less noisy IMHO:

```
$:.unshift File.expand_path("../../src", __FILE__)
require 'myclass'
```

or just

```
require File.expand_path "../../src/myclass", __FILE__
```

Tested with ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.0 on (Debian) Linux - please tell me if it works on Windows, too.

Why a simpler method (eg. 'use', 'require_relative', or sg like this) isn't built into the standard lib? UPDATE: require_relative is there since 1.9.x

Comment: While it makes my spine tingle, this is the best option I've seen for doing this _inside_ of ruby so far.

Comment: That is to say, I prefer appending (not prepending) the path to the ruby path, as you don't inadvertently stomp over something that exists in the standard ruby libraries.

Comment: Didn't you mean 'I prefer prepending (not appending)' instead? (in other words: don't you actually want to make sure your stuff to take precedence?) My original example was '$:<< newpath' which was appending, now fixed it by 'unshift', as the previous reply did. Thanks

Comment: Matt, 'best option I've seen for doing this inside of ruby so far' -- are there some options outside of ruby? Like preprocessor or something?

Comment: @inger, options for doing it outside ruby are shell variables and ruby command line arguments.

Comment: NB: The first `../` in the path here just removes the file name of the `__FILE__` from the path. It does not go up in the folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

```
Pathname(__FILE__).dirname.realpath
```

provides a the absolute path in a dynamic way.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code to require all "rb" files in specific folder (=> Ruby 1.9):

```
path='../specific_folder/' # relative path from current file to required folder

Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/'+path+'*.rb'].each do |file|
  require_relative path+File.basename(file) # require all files with .rb extension in this folder
end
```

Answer (score 1):

sris's answer is the standard approach.

Another way would be to package your code as a gem.  Then rubygems will take care of making sure your library files are in your path.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with - a Ruby version of a `setenv` shell script:

```
  # Read application config                                                       
$hConf, $fConf = {}, File.expand_path("../config.rb", __FILE__)
$hConf = File.open($fConf) {|f| eval(f.read)} if File.exist? $fConf

  # Application classpath                                                         
$: << ($hConf[:appRoot] || File.expand_path("../bin/app", __FILE__))

  # Ruby libs                                                                     
$lib = ($hConf[:rubyLib] || File.expand_path("../bin/lib", __FILE__))
($: << [$lib]).flatten! # lib is string or array, standardize
```

Then I just need to make sure that this script is called once before anything else, and don't need to touch the individual source files.

I put some options inside a config file, like the location of external (non-gem) libraries:

```
# Site- and server specific config - location of DB, tmp files etc.
{
  :webRoot => "/srv/www/myapp/data",
  :rubyLib => "/somewhere/lib",
  :tmpDir => "/tmp/myapp"
}
```

This has been working well for me, and I can reuse the setenv script in multiple projects just by changing the parameters in the config file. A much better alternative than shell scripts, IMO.

Comment: @j-g-faustus: "Merging __ FILE __  with the working directory ensures that I can call it from wherever":
File.expand_path(path, base) should have the same effect.
Are you sure inger's answer above didn't do the job?
What does this give you? (put it in test.rb, for example):

"puts File.expand_path "../../src/myclass", __ FILE __ "

Comment: You're right, File.expand_path does the same. I've updated the post. It does become a bit cleaner, thanks :)
Apart from that, the primary difference is that this is a separate script run once at application startup, and I don't need to touch the individual source files.