# Why doesn't relative_require work on Ruby 1.8.6?

Tags: ruby, require

I'm learning Ruby (using version 1.8.6) on Windows 7.

When I try to run the **stock_stats.rb** program below, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Will\Desktop\ruby>ruby stock_stats.rb
stock_stats.rb:1: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodE
rror)
```

I have three v.small code files:

**stock_stats.rb**

```
require_relative 'csv_reader'

reader = CsvReader.new

ARGV.each do |csv_file_name|
  STDERR.puts "Processing #{csv_file_name}"
  reader.read_in_csv_data(csv_file_name)
end

puts "Total value = #{reader.total_value_in_stock}"
```

**csv_reader.rb**

```
require 'csv' 
require_relative 'book_in_stock'

class CsvReader

  def initialize
    @books_in_stock = []
  end

  def read_in_csv_data(csv_file_name)
    CSV.foreach(csv_file_name, headers: true) do |row|
      @books_in_stock << BookInStock.new(row["ISBN"], row["Amount"])
    end
  end  

  # later we'll see how to use inject to sum a collection
  def total_value_in_stock
    sum = 0.0        
    @books_in_stock.each {|book| sum += book.price}
    sum
  end  

  def number_of_each_isbn
    # ...
  end

end
```

**book_in_stock.rb**

```
require 'csv' 
require_relative 'book_in_stock'

class CsvReader

  def initialize
    @books_in_stock = []
  end

  def read_in_csv_data(csv_file_name)
    CSV.foreach(csv_file_name, headers: true) do |row|
      @books_in_stock << BookInStock.new(row["ISBN"], row["Amount"])
    end
  end  

  # later we'll see how to use inject to sum a collection
  def total_value_in_stock
    sum = 0.0        
    @books_in_stock.each {|book| sum += book.price}
    sum
  end  

  def number_of_each_isbn
    # ...
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That's the code from chapter 3 on the Pickaxe book!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:**

Back in the days where this question was asked it referred to Ruby 1.8.6 where there was no `require_relative`. By now Ruby 1.8.6 is outdated and shouldn't be used anymore.

**Original:**

There is simply no method name `require_relative`. You can use `require` there aswell.

The `require_relative` function is included in an extension project to the Ruby core libraries, found here: http://www.rubyforge.org/projects/extensions

You should be able to install them with `gem install extensions`.
Then in your code add the following line before the `require_relative`:

```
require 'extensions/all'
```

Comment: There is, but it's in 1.9 only.

Comment: @molf: I was only looking for the specified version.

Comment: Thanks very much, I've installed the newer version of Ruby and it works.

Answer (score 34):

`require_relative` doesn't exist in your version of Ruby. You could upgrade Ruby, install the [backports](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem and `require 'backports/1.9.1/kernel/require/relative'` but the easiest fix will be to change your require to:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'csv_reader')
```

Comment: Thanks Shanna, really appreciate your advice

Comment: suggest to use `require File.expand_path('another_file', __FILE__)` which can nicely resolve parent directory if you need to load `'../csv_reader'`