# Ruby: require vs require_relative - best practice to workaround running in both Ruby <1.9.2 and >=1.9.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

What is the best practice if I want to `require` a relative file in Ruby *and* I want it to work in both 1.8.x and >=1.9.2?

I see a few options:

- just do `$LOAD_PATH << '.'` and forget everything
- do `$LOAD_PATH << File.dirname(__FILE__)`
- `require './path/to/file'`
- check if `RUBY_VERSION` < 1.9.2, then define `require_relative` as `require`, use `require_relative` everywhere where it's needed afterwards
- check if `require_relative` already exists, if it does, try to proceed as in previous case
- use weird constructions such as `require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'path/to/file')` - alas they don't seem to work in Ruby 1.9 throughly, because, for example:

  ```
  $ cat caller.rb
  require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'path/to/file')
  $ cat path/to/file.rb
  puts 'Some testing'
  $ ruby caller
  Some testing
  $ pwd
  /tmp
  $ ruby /tmp/caller
  Some testing
  $ ruby tmp/caller
  tmp/caller.rb:1:in 'require': no such file to load -- tmp/path/to/file (LoadError)
      from tmp/caller.rb:1:in '<main>'
  ```
- Even weirder construction: `require File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'path/to/file')` seems to work, but it's weird and not quite good looking.
- Use [backports](http://rubygems.org/gems/backports) gem - it's kind of heavy, it requires rubygems infrastructure and includes tons of other workarounds, while I just want `require` to work with relative files.

There's a [closely related question at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325759/is-require-file-expand-path-file-the-best-practice) that gives some more examples, but it doesn't give a clear answer - which is a best practice.

Is there are any decent, accepted-by-everyone universal solution to make my application run on both Ruby <1.9.2 and >=1.9.2?

### UPDATE

Clarification: I don't want just answers like "you can do X" - in fact, I've already mentioned most of choices in question. I want *rationale*, i.e. *why* it is a best practice, what are its pros and cons and why it should be chosen among the others.

Comment: Hi I'm new. Could someone explain from the start—what's the difference between `require` and `require_relative`?

Comment: In older Ruby 1.8 if you ran file `a.rb` and wanted to make interpreter read and parse contents of file `b.rb` in current directory (usually the same dir as with `a.rb`), you'd just write `require 'b'` and it would be fine as default search path included current directory. In more modern Ruby 1.9, you'll have to write `require_relative 'b'` in this case, as `require 'b'` would only search in standard library paths. That's the thing that kind of breaks forward and backward compatibility for simpler scripts that aren't going to be installed properly (for example, *install* scripts themselves).

Comment: You can now use `backports` just for `require_relative`, see my answer...

Answer (score 64):

A workaround for this was just added to the 'aws' gem so thought I'd share as it was inspired by this post.

https://github.com/appoxy/aws/blob/master/lib/awsbase/require_relative.rb

```
unless Kernel.respond_to?(:require_relative)
  module Kernel
    def require_relative(path)
      require File.join(File.dirname(caller[0]), path.to_str)
    end
  end
end
```

This allows you to use `require_relative` as you would in ruby 1.9.2 in ruby 1.8 and 1.9.1.

Comment: How do you require the require_relative.rb file? You have to require require_relative.rb and then require_relative the rest of the requires. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The `require_relative` function is included in an extension project to the Ruby core libraries, found here: http://www.rubyforge.org/projects/extensions

You should be able to install them with `gem install extensions`.
Then in your code add the following line before the `require_relative`:

    require 'extensions/all' 

(sourced from Aurril's post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681031/why-doesnt-relative-require-work-on-ruby-1-8-6))

Comment: @ethicalhack3r just copy and paste that code at the top of your ruby script or if in rails, throw it in at the top environment.rb or something.

Answer (score 46):

Before I made the jump to 1.9.2 I used the following for relative requires:

```
require File.expand_path('../relative/path', __FILE__)
```

It's a bit weird the first time you see it, because it looks like there's an extra '..' at the start. The reason is that `expand_path` will expand a path relative to the second argument, and the second argument will be interpreted as if it were a directory. `__FILE__` obviously isn't a directory, but that doesn't matter since `expand_path` doesn't care if the files exist or not, it will just apply some rules to expand things like `..`, `.` and `~`. If you can get over the initial "waitaminute isn't there an extra `..` there?" I think that the line above works quite well.

Assuming that `__FILE__` is `/absolute/path/to/file.rb`, what happens is that `expand_path` will construct the string `/absolute/path/to/file.rb/../relative/path`, and then apply a rule that says that `..` should remove the path component before it (`file.rb` in this case), returning `/absolute/path/to/relative/path`.

Is this best practice? Depends on what you mean by that, but it seems like it's all over the Rails code base, so I'd say it's at least a common enough idiom.

Comment: I see this commonly as well. It's ugly, but it seems to work well.

Comment: a bit cleaner: require File.expand_path('relative/path', File.dirname(__FILE__))

Comment: I don't think it's much cleaner, it's just longer. They are both fugly as hell, and when choosing between two bad options I prefer the one that requires less typing.

Comment: It seems that File.expand_path('../relpath.x', File.dirname(__FILE__)) is a better idiom, even though it is more verbose.  Relying on the arguably broken functionality of a file path being interpreted as a directory path with an extra nonexistent directory might break when/if that functionality is fixed.

Comment: Broken, perhaps, but it's been that way forever in UNIX. There's just no difference between a directory and a file when it comes to paths and the resolution of '..' -- so I'm not loosing any sleep over it.

Comment: Thank You. Most concise answer I have seen on the weird `..`

Comment: @Theo Can you give an example of that?  It's clearly not true in the most obvious cases, e.g. `cd path/to/a/file/../..` fails.

Answer (score 6):

The Pickaxe has a snippet for this for 1.8. Here it is:

```
def require_relative(relative_feature)
  c = caller.first
  fail "Can't parse #{c}" unless c.rindex(/:\d+(:in `.*')?$/)
  file = $`
  if /\A\((.*)\)/ =~ file # eval, etc.
    raise LoadError, "require_relative is called in #{$1}"
  end
  absolute = File.expand_path(relative_feature, File.dirname(file))
  require absolute
end
```

It basically just uses what Theo answered, but so you can still use `require_relative`.

Comment: How to check if this snippet should be activated or not properly? Using `$RUBY_VERSION` or by checking if `require_relative` exists directly?

Comment: Always duck type, check if `require_relative` is defined.

Comment: @Theo @GreyCat yes, I would check if it's needed. I was just putting the snippet here for people to show. Personally, I use would Greg's answer anyways, I was really just posting this because someone had mentioned it without having it themselves.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> $LOAD_PATH << '.'
>
> $LOAD_PATH << File.dirname(__FILE__)
> ```

It's not a good security habit: why should you expose your whole directory?

> ```
> require './path/to/file'
> ```

This doesn't work if RUBY_VERSION < 1.9.2

> use weird constructions such as
>
> ```
> require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'path/to/file')
> ```
>
> Even weirder construction:
>
> ```
> require File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'path/to/file')
> ```
>
> Use backports gem - it's kind of heavy, it requires rubygems
>   infrastructure and includes tons of other workarounds, while I just
>   want require to work with relative files.

You have already answered why these are not the best options.

> check if RUBY_VERSION < 1.9.2, then define require_relative as
>   require, use require_relative everywhere where it's needed afterwards
>
> check if require_relative already exists, if it does, try to proceed
>   as in previous case

This may work, but there's safer and quicker way: to deal with the LoadError exception:

```
begin
  # require statements for 1.9.2 and above, such as:
  require "./path/to/file"
  # or
  require_local "path/to/file"
rescue LoadError
  # require statements other versions:
  require "path/to/file"
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm a fan of using the rbx-require-relative gem ([source](https://github.com/rocky/rbx-require-relative/blob/master/lib/require_relative.rb)). It was originally written for Rubinius, but it also supports MRI 1.8.7 and does nothing in 1.9.2. Requiring a gem is simple, and I don't have to throw code snippets into my project.

Add it to your Gemfile:

```
gem "rbx-require-relative"
```

Then `require 'require_relative'` before you `require_relative`.

For example, one of my test files looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'require_relative'
require_relative '../lib/foo'
```

This is the cleanest solution out of any of these IMO, and the gem isn't as heavy as backports.

Answer (score 4):

The [`backports`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem now allows individual loading of backports.

You could then simply:

```
require 'backports/1.9.1/kernel/require_relative'
# => Now require_relative works for all versions of Ruby
```

This `require` will not affect newer versions, nor will it update any other builtin methods.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to tell the interpreter which paths to search

```
ruby -I /path/to/my/project caller.rb
```

Answer (score 3):

One issue I've not seen pointed out with the solutions based on __FILE__ is that they break with regards to symlinks. For example say I have:

```
~/Projects/MyProject/foo.rb
~/Projects/MyProject/lib/someinclude.rb
```

The main script, the entry point, the application is foo.rb. This file is linked to ~/Scripts/foo which is in my $PATH. This require statement is broken when I execute 'foo':

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "lib/someinclude")
```

Because __FILE__ is ~/Scripts/foo so the require statement above looks for ~/Scripts/foo/lib/someinclude.rb which obviously doesn't exist. The solution is simple. If __FILE__ is a symbolic link it needs to be dereferenced. Pathname#realpath will help us with this situation:

```
require "pathname"
require File.join(File.dirname(Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath), "lib/someinclude")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were building a gem, you would not want to pollute the load path.

But, In the case of a standalone application it is very convenient to just add the current directory to the load path as you do in the first 2 examples.

My vote goes to the first option on the list.

I would love to see some solid Ruby best practices literature.

Comment: Re: "I would love to see some solid Ruby best practices literature." You can download Gregory Brown's [_Ruby Best Practices_](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/022-rbp-now-open.html). You can also check out the [Rails Best Practices site](http://rails-bestpractices.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I would define my own `relative_require` if it doesn't exist (i.e. under 1.8) and then use the same syntax everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails way:

```
config_path = File.expand_path("../config.yml", __FILE__)
```