# Calling another ruby file that is not a gem

Tags: ruby, class, file

I want to create a static ruby class with a library of function. I am on Vista with ruby 1.9.2

My class is this one :

```
class TestClass

  def say_hello
    puts "say hello"
  end
end
```

in a TestClass.rb file (I assume I am correct as all ruby tutorials on classes are a complete mess putting everything in a single magic something (file?) as if IRB was the begining and the end of all thing).

My ruby `main()` (yes I come from Java) or program entry or wathever it is called in ruby is :

```
require 'TestClass.rb'

puts "start"
say_hello
```

But it fails with :

```
C:\ruby_path_with_all_my_classes>ruby classuser.rb
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load --
 TestClass.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from classuser.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

How does it work? Is it possible to call other files in Ruby or are you trapped in only one file containing all your classes?

Comment: Don't put `[Ruby]` at the start of a question. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In 99% of all cases when a computer tells you that it couldn't find a thing, it is because the thing isn't there. So, the first thing you need to check is whether there actually *is* a file named `TestClass.rb` somewhere on your filesystem.

In 99% of the *rest* of the cases, the computer is looking in the wrong place. (Well, actually, the computer is usually looking in the right place, but the thing it is looking for is in the wrong place). `require` loads a file from the `$LOAD_PATH`, so you have to make sure that the directory that the file `TestClass.rb` is in actually *is* on the `$LOAD_PATH`.

Alternatively, if you do not want to `require` a file from the `$LOAD_PATH` but rather relative to the position of the file that is *doing* the `require`ing, then you need to use `require_relative`.

Note, however, that your code won't work anyway, since `say_hello` is in instance method of instances of the `TestClass` class, but you are calling it on the `main` object, which is an instance of `Object`, not `TestClass`.

Note also that standard naming conventions of Ruby files are `snake_case`, in particular, the `snake_case` version of the primary class/module of the file. So, in your case, the file should be named `test_class.rb`. Also, `require` and `require_relative` figure out the correct file extension for themselves, so you should leave off the `.rb`. And thirdly, standard Ruby coding style is two spaces for indentation, not four.

None of these will lead to your code not working, of course, since it is purely stylistic, but it *may* lead to people being unwilling to answer your questions, since it shows that you don't respect their community enough to learn even the most basic rules.

Comment: I was using class in the same folder, so i was pretty sure that the error was something else than the name space.
Thanks, there is not a lot of informations on ruby files out there, and require search results are all about rubygems.

Answer (score 17):

Is the TestClass file in the same dir?
Make the TestClass.rb file lowercase and load it with

```
require './testclass'
```

no need for the .rb

I'd suggest putting any classes in a lib folder.
Then you require file as follows:

```
require './lib/testclass'
```

Comment: It works fine, thanks! Oh and for static class, i use self.methodname

Comment: yep, self creates static class methods in ruby

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
require './TestClass.rb'
```

Related: [Ruby: require vs require_relative - best practice to workaround running in both Ruby <1.9.2 and >=1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333286/ruby-require-vs-require-relative-best-practice-to-workaround-running-in-both-r)