# Problem using require command

Tags: ruby, require, ruby-1.9.2

I am simply requiring a file present in the same folder as the testfile however I am getting this wierd message again and again...

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- a.rb (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from C:/dummyFirefox/test_a.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

the code that I write in my testfile test_a.rb is simply:

```
require 'a.rb'
```

and when I issue the command : `rspec test_a.rb` the message is the above mentioned error.

I am using ruby-1.9.2 for development.

Hope I don't miss any details.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling another ruby file that is not a gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491049/calling-another-ruby-file-that-is-not-a-gem)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9.2 the current working directory is no longer part of the load path (`$LOAD_PATH` or `$:`). You have to add it manually using:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift '.'
```

or

```
$:.unshift '.'
```

Or you can require the file explicitly:

```
require './test_a.rb'
```