# Ruby Module Help -- Looking in wrong directory?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module

Hey everyone!  I am having trouble with understanding modules -- I have two files, one named "modfile.rb" with the module, and one named "main.rb" that runs the code:

```
# modfile.rb  
module Module1
  def method1
    puts "SUCCESS!"
  end
end

# main.rb  
require 'modfile'
Module1.method1
```

Unfortunately, instead of SUCCESS! appearing on my screen, I get this:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in 'require': no such file to load -- modfile (LoadError)
  from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in 'require'
  from main.rb:1:in '<main>'
```

I think (though I may be wrong) that Ruby is looking to the lib/.... file inside the Ruby directory on my computer, while modfile.rb is saved in the same directory as main.rb.  How do I fix this problem (other than by moving the module's file?)

PS. one guide suggested I add the line "require 'rubygems'" but I already did and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If modfile.rb and main.rb are in the same directory, make sure that you aare calling main.rb from the directory it's in, ie:

```
ruby main.rb
```

As I believe that is the directory that the Ruby interpreter will be looking in for any require files.

**Edit**: as @the-tin-man points out, the behaviour has changed for Ruby 1.9.

To be completely on the safe side, you can do:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "modfile")
```

One other thing:

```
def method1
```

... should be:

```
def self.method1
```

... since you are calling the method as a class level method.

Answer (score 1):

Check into the differences between `require` and `require_relative` in [Ruby: require vs require_relative - best practice to workaround running in both Ruby <1.9.2 and >=1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333286/ruby-require-vs-require-relative-best-practice-to-workaround-running-in-both-r)

In Ruby 1.9 the `.` directory was removed from the search path. To fix the problem this generated they added `require_relative`.

Comment: And how would this code look if I wanted to use "include" instead of "require"?

Comment: I didn't suggest using `include`. Use `require_relative`.

Comment: also, is there a way to mark more than one answer to a question correct?  Because I wanted to check your response as well