# Requiring files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, path, require

I'm building a web app in Sinatra and I have a bunch of files in /lib/checkers/

I'm currently requiring them by doing this:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/checkers/board.rb')
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/checkers/checker.rb')
```

which seems dumb but I have tried

```
require '/lib/checkers'
```

or

```
require '/lib/checkers/'
```

or

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + 'lib/checkers/')
```

and other variants along the same them but nothing seems to work. Can you help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735073/best-way-to-require-all-files-from-a-directory-in-ruby

Comment: put the `lib` directory into your include path `$:` (if it's not already there) and then just `require 'checkers/board'` and `require 'checkers/checker'`.

Comment: Nah, you needn't use the techniques from that other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require_relative 'lib/checkers/board'
require_relative 'lib/checkers/checker'
```

This is how I have always done it. This is located in my main app file, which is always in the root directory. I'm unsure how it will behave from other files, although I believe it will be relative to the calling file.

Also, `settings.root` will return the root directory of your app, no need for `File.dirname(__FILE__)` anywhere.

This works in Ruby 1.9 without any special techniques via the comments above.

If you are using 1.8, you can do this

```
require './lib/checkers/board'
require './lib/checkers/checker'
```

Other techniques for 1.8 are listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333286/ruby-require-vs-require-relative-best-practice-to-workaround-running-in-both).

Comment: Note that require_relative is only available in Ruby >= 1.9.2. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333286/ruby-require-vs-require-relative-best-practice-to-workaround-running-in-both) for more info if you choose to go with this solution.

Comment: @louism thanks for reminding me. I started learning Ruby with 1.9, so I tend to forget issues in 1.8.