# Error referencing module constants as a :default in an ActiveRecord::Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am trying to set a default value on an attribute by pointing to a Module constant, but things are not going to plan. Relevant code includes:

```
[lib/establishments.rb]
module Establishments
  BAR = "Bar"
  RESTAURANT = "Restaurant"
  BENEFIT = "Benefit"
end

[20140321164012_add_type_to_discount]
include Establishments
class AddTypeToDiscount < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    add_column :discounts, :type, :string, :default => Establishments::RESTAURANT
  end
end

rake db:migrate
```

Above code results in:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant Establishments/home/bob/Dev/app/db/migrate/20140321164012_add_type_to_discount.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Looks to me that the `/lib` path is not being picked up by `rake`. I'm not sure how to influence that.

I have also tried adding:

```
require 'lib/establishments.rb'
```

To the top of the migration file, but that complains of no such file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/establishments"
```

Then you are able to use `Establishments::RESTAURANT`

Answer (score 1):

Use `require_relative '../../lib/establishments'` instead of `include Establishments`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, all valid - just as I found (equally valid)

```
require File.expand_path('lib/establishments')
```

Comment: ah yes but who gets the answer vote - i am literally going to toss a coin :)

Comment: Hahaha.:) If I may suggest, choose markets, he was 4 secs faster than me.

Comment: Well, he deserved it :)

Comment: @KirtiThorat I found this with more options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333286/ruby-require-vs-require-relative-best-practice-to-workaround-running-in-both.