# Cannot Load Such File -- config/application Rails App Heroku Require Links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, hosting

I spent the last few weeks learning how to code using a Udemy course and Codecademy while building a website for the company I am working at. I built it using Ruby on Rails, which I do not have a very good understanding of at the moment. I am currently attempting to get the app working on a Hostgator server. I was using a more recent version of Ruby and Rails than supported by Hostgator, as I recently found out, and I have been working through this guide, fixing errors as I go: http://support.hostgator.in/articles/specialized-help/technical/how-do-i-start-using-ruby-on-rails

My most recent issue is that require_relative is unsupported. I had connected to SSH in the terminal and ran the command `rake generate_session_store`, which returned this error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object
```

After doing some research on what this was, I decided to change find all instances of 'require_relative' in my document and change them to 'require'. I then pushed the site to Heroku to find out if the site still worked. This is the error I got:

```
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- config/application
```

Running 'bundle exec rake -P' shows the bottom line above on top and has a lot of other information following. Here's my Rakefile, which appears to be the source of the problem:

```
require 'config/application'

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

The require used to be require_relative so I know the problem is there. I've tried changing the link path to all kinds of different things. I believe the file being referenced is the application.rb file, so I've added the extension, added '/socascade/' (my app folder) to the beginning of the link, and attempted some other fixes using the few resources I was able to find. No luck so far. Here's my directory structure if that would help:

```
socascade
-config
--environments
---development.rb
---production.rb
---test.rb
--initializers
---application_controller_renderer.rb
---assets.rb
---backtrace_silencers.rb
---cookies_serializer.rb
---filter_parameter_logging.rb
---inflections.rb
---mime_types.rb
---simple_form.rb
---wrap_parameters.rb
--locales
---en.yml
---simple_form.en.yml
--application.rb
--boot.rb
--cable.yml
--database.yml
--environment.rb
--puma.rb
--routes.rb
--secrets.yml
--spring.rb
```

If this is something extremely simple, please understand that I literally started coding about four or five weeks ago, so most of this is new to me. I couldn't find a solution after about half an hour of searching, so that's where I'm coming from now. Thanks in advance

Comment: try changing everything that was require_relative back to require_relative. Heroku shouldn't have any problems supporting it. require and require_relative are very different

Comment: Heroku had no problems at all. My issue was with trying to host the site on Hostgator. I connected to SSH in the terminal and attempted to 'rake generate_session_store' and received the error 'undefined method 'require_relative' for main:Object'. I guess I should add that to my question

Comment: got it. require takes an absolute path, so if your root directory isn't added to the load path then you need the full path name. the second answer (32 upvotes) to this linked question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681031/why-doesnt-relative-require-work-on-ruby-1-8-6

Comment: do you have to use hostgator? if it doesn't support require_relative then it's using a very old version of ruby that also won't be supported by the versions of rails that are still receiving security patches. you'll be cementing your app in a more vulnerable (and slower) past

Comment: Alright, I used that and now at least I have a different error (making progress): `remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- /tmp/build_ab39d76053c0a0d22b0666e145ee9b00/Rakefile/application`

Comment: Using Hostgator was decided by the company, if it was my choice I probably would just host using Heroku but oh well. The site is just a simple, static site with a contact form that emails the entries directly to our support address. Is that risky to store on low security?

Comment: Solved it, I think! I hadn't added 'config/', just 'application.' After adding that it's giving me another error from another section of the code. Now I know what to do. Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it

Comment: Just make sure you're not hardcoding any sensitive data and you will probably be fine, but you will be unsupported by any future unforeseen security patches. Glad you were able to solve your issue!